# Center a gameobject using raycast hit information

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm building a walkable path who is checked by a gameobject (capsule) using raycast pointing down, every cube have a direction to move the capsule in the right way. The problem is the capsule moves immediately the raycast hit the cube, therefore the capsule moves along the edge, but center.

Here the code I use

```
RayDirection = (direction) => new Ray(transform.position, direction);

if (Physics.Raycast(RayDirection(-transform.up), out RaycastHit hit, 1.5f, 1 << 9))
{
    switch (hit.transform.GetComponent<Path>().path)
    {
        case Path.Forward:
            transform.position += Vector3.forward / 50;
            break;
        case Path.Back:
            transform.position += Vector3.back / 50;
            break;
        case Path.Right:
            transform.position += Vector3.right / 50;
            break;
        case Path.Left:
            transform.position += Vector3.left / 50;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get the position where you hit right? How about checking if it is same as your cubes' position and then applying this switch case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than having the path elements contain a direction, you could have them contain an exit location. This could be set in the designer by an empty object, or computed when the path object is initialized.

Then in your raycast hit you could get that exit location and move your character in that direction.

While you're at it, it looks like you're using " / 50 " to slow down the movement. This could be done by adding a Speed variable (in meters per second) to the character. To move the character multiply the move direction * Speed * Time.DeltaTime (to account for different frame-rates).